# Classification:adding a new variable and calculate probabilty of changing the class output

Tags: machine-learning, classification, probability

I have 2 output classes (good and poor) based on several numeric features (say, v1…. v20).

If v1, v2, v3 and v4 are “high”, then the class is “poor”.
If v1, v2, v3 and v4 are “low”, then the class is “good”

I am able to get good accuracy like this, using ROC and minimum classification error using Random Forest.
But, I want to add a new variable, v21. I know from experience that if the value of this variable (v21) is high, the class may not be “poor”, even if v1, v2, v3 and v4 are high.  The probability of getting a “poor” class is low, when variable v21 is high (although the variables v1, v2, v3 and v4 are high).

1)How can I use my knowledge about v21 in the classification to improve the accuracy? And which is the suitable classification technique?
2)As I have real data that matches my understanding, is there anyway, I can calculate the probability of getting a “poor” class when value of v21 is high and when values of v1, v2, v3 and v4 are high?

Comment: what are you algorithm using currently to determine poor or good?

Comment: I am currently using Random Forest in R

Answer (score 1):

Bayesian Probability allows incorporating your *prior* belief and knowledge by selecting a prior distribution.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prior_probability

In that way your *actuals* data will be merged with the prior beliefs to form your final posterior distribution.

So your prior distribution in this case should include information that

```
P(myclass =poor|v1,v2,v3,v4) is high
P(myclass =poor|v21) is low
```

Comment: Thanks.  If any R packages available  to calculate  , please let me know

Comment: @user5795923 The simplest assumption is that, given the class, v21 is independent of v1, ..., v20. If that's reasonable (and the only way to know that is to study the data) then you can take v21 into account via a simple "naive Bayes" model. I doubt if there is a package to handle it, as it's just simple arithmetic.

Answer (score 0):

I have had similar problems. Even when I have prior knowledge about the effect of a variable, I often just run an unbiased algorithm, like an SVM, to classify the data. I then check to see accurate my SVM was. I also check to see if the SVM agrees with what I already know about the variables. If the SVM fails, I then try a neural network. Hope this helped!

Comment: Good.  The classifier is already doing a good job-means accuracy of classification is 96~97%. Wanted to know if prior knowledge can improve accuracy or improve any measure such as MAE, F - measure or p - values.

Comment: Note that the new feature does not always result in change of class.  It only increases the chances of the class being "good".